# Google place API for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, geocoding, google-places-api, clgeocoder

I am trying to find location of places with business names.
I think I should use Google Place API as `CLGeocoder` cannot locate place with name.

So I looked at the Google Place API and got little confused about the part of location field.

I think I am supposed to enter location and radius and optionally name to search.

And I am not sure what location I should enter to find the place when I don't know the location. What I want is location searched from name.

Then, should I use `CLGeocoder` to find out approximate location and give really huge radius with that location to Google Place API?

For example, If I want to find a certain hotel in LA, then, should I use `CLGeocoder` to find out the approximate location and then feed that value to Google Place API?

Or is there any other options?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You mentioned of "confused about the part of location field", which google place API call do you refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Your approche is good - in one of my applications you can enter an address and after entering the address I use the CLGeoCoder to get the placemarks with the coordinates.

```
CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geoCoder geocodeAddressString:addressString completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

    if (placemarks && placemarks.count>0) 
    {
        if(placemarks.count==1)
        {
            MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([[[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] location] coordinate], 1000, 1000);

            [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
            [mapView regionThatFits:region];
        }
   }
```

THe placemark has the property coordinate which you can use for the google places API

Comment: When given my address string it showing error : Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 8.)"